# Android - How to access Radio Button outside onCreateView?

Tags: android, radio-button

I need access to Radio Button outside `onCreateView()`

```
public void loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);
    int array[] = new int[size];

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        array[i] = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_" + i, 0);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Of course `findViewById()` is not resolved here, inside `onCreateView()`, I can easily do `rootView.findViewById()`

Comment: Its considered best practice to store any views you need by finding them once in onCreateView in class level variables.  findViewById isn't cheap, you don't want to call it all the time.  Here an array or list of radio buttons would make sense.

Comment: You can also save your RadioButton globally, set it in onCreateView() and do something in your loadArray().

Comment: @GabeSechan Ok, I have put all the required radio buttons inside an array but the problem is now I can't save their state in Shared Preferences. It doesn't allow to store radio buttons, I can store int or string though and if I store radio button id, then this `findViewById` question will arise yet again.

Comment: @GabeSechan Example - inside `onCheckedChange()`, I'm using `allRadio[radioGroup.getId()-1] = radio` which works but the problem is sharedPreferences, now I can't really save RadioButton array in them, as in the question above, I'm easily able to store required radio button ids in shared preferences but in the end it has become useless. So both approaches doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @GabeSechan I've posted a question on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257874/how-to-store-and-access-radio-buttons-from-shared-preferences).

Comment: @buczek Yeah I've done that but then how to store them in shared preferences, have a look at my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257874/how-to-store-and-access-radio-buttons-from-shared-preferences).

Comment: what does the command `(RadioButton) findViewById(array[i]);` return?

Comment: @ddb `findViewById()` cannot be resolved.

Comment: `loadArray` is called in an `Activity`? basically, if I understand well, you want to access to some UI Elements from somewhere else that an `Activity` or a generic `Fragment`, am I?

Comment: @ddb The code is inside a fragment.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria, is `loadArray` called before or after the `onCreateView`? it should called when you are sure that `RadioButton`s exist. You can't access something it does not exist