# How to store and access Radio Buttons from Shared Preferences?

Tags: android, radio-button

There are a lot of questions on SO about saving radio buttons state in Shared Preferences but none of them provide the solution that I'm looking for.

I'm creating 15 radio groups and 4 radio buttons inside each radio group in a for loop. The radio groups have unique id from 1 to 15 and the radio buttons have ids ranging from 100 to 159.

This is the code I use to save radio buttons id:

```
public void saveArray(int[] array, String arrayName) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        editor.putInt(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

`array` contains the unique ID of all those radio buttons that are checked and I've tested the above code, it works perfectly but the problem is I can't access it.

This is the code I use to retrieve radio button id:

```
public void loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);
    int array[] = new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        array[i] = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_" + i, 0);

    }
}
```

Like `saveArray`, `loadArray` also works. The array is populated by the correct radio button ids.
The problem starts now - I can't access those radio buttons, I can't do `findViewById()` because that is only available in `onCreateView()`

So this will not work inside `loadArray`

```
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(array[i]);
    }
```

The possible solution to `findViewById` is storing the views in `onCreateView()` and then accessing it later. So I created a Radio Button array

```
RadioButton[] allRadio = new RadioButton[15];
```

Now inside `onCheckedChanged`, I'm adding the selected radio buttons to the array:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
        RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(i);
        String selectedValue = radio.getText().toString();
        allRadio[radioGroup.getId()-1] = radio;
}
```

The above code perfectly stores the radio buttons inside the array but now I can't save them! You can store int, string etc.. in Shared Preferences but not radio buttons! The solution to this could be to store radio button id but then the same problem will start all over again that `findViewById()` is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);
    int array[] = new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        array[i] = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_" + i, 0);
//->put Toast here and check whether your are getting the id's or not. If you
//->are getting it, return arrays of id back to calling method
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you made it look so easy. Returning the array did the trick, thanks!